# Netbeans + project groups: how can I tweak, where Netbeans stores information about created project groups?

Tags: ide, netbeans

When coding, I use Dropbox to sync folder in which I keep my projects between 3 computers.

I use Netbeans as an IDE, and so - I create project groups very often. While creating them, I usually choose "Folder of Projects" option, so it includes all projects found in specific folder.

Is it possible to tweak Netbeans, that it would store information about created project groups in specific place? Is there any option which changes this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans stores the groups information in:

{netbeans_user_root}/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/projectui/groups

I doubt that this can be changed.

Comment: Where `{netbeans_user_root}` is like `~/.netbeans/{netbeans_version_number}` on linux, and like `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\NetBeans\{netbeans_version_number}` on Windows.  And where `{netbeans_version_number}` all depends on what you installed. :)  For me it is `8.0.2`.